# How do I 'intercept' or connect the event handler of a nested control to the wrapping custom control?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am creating a custom control from a Border that wraps around any data entry control (Entry, Editor, DatePicker, TimePicker, etc), but I now have the requirement to alter the colors of the border to change whenever the nested object's focus changes.

It looks something like this:
[image: Image Example 1]

So, there is a border, a label that acts as a placeholder, and the entry itself.

```
<controls:CustomBorder
     Placeholder="{localization:Translate SMSHint}"
     BorderColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
     Padding="10,10,10,6"
     CornerRadius="RoundRectangle 10"
     ErrorVisible="False"
     OptionalVisible="False"
     PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource Gray600}">
     <controls:CustomBorder.NestedContent>
          <Entry
               IsFocused="This Is The Event I want to bind to the border control"
               HorizontalOptions="Fill"
               Keyboard="Default"
               Text="{Binding SMSCode}">
               <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <toolkit:MaskedBehavior Mask="XXX XXX" />
               </Entry.Behaviors>
         </Entry>
     </controls:CustomBorder.NestedContent>
</controls:CustomBorder>
```

All of the properties for CustomBorder properties, I'm binding them like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty FocusedBorderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(FocusedBorderColor),
            typeof(Color),
            typeof(CustomBorder),
            Colors.Orange,
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

public Color FocusedBorderColor
{
    get => (Color)GetValue(FocusedBorderColorProperty);
    set => SetValue(FocusedBorderColorProperty, value);
}
```

Is there a tutorial or something that will help me understand how to bind eventhandlers in the way that I'm thinking of?

Comment: How does your `NestedContent`-property look? Whenever this changes you should be able to attach an event handler to Got/LostFocus.

Comment: I thought about that, but it's not always going to be just the object in there. There are situations where there is a grid with an Entry and an ImageButton, and I want it tied to the Entry only but then I'd have to attach the handler to the NestedContent and the Grid to the Entry, right?

Comment: Couldn't you subscribe to the inner object's PropertyChanged event?

Comment: You could also try using maui community toolkit [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior). Also, BindableProperties can [detect property changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-8.0#detect-property-changes) by property-changed callback method .

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is using [VisualState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states?view=net-maui-8.0). We could change the Stroke of Border depends on whether the Entry is focused or not.

An example here, I [Define visual states in a style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states?view=net-maui-8.0#define-visual-states-in-a-style)

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Entry" x:Key="style1">
       
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter
                                TargetName="myBorder" Property="Border.Stroke" Value="Blue" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter
                                TargetName="myBorder" Property="Border.Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Then for the control,

```
<controls:CustomBorder x:Name="myBorder"
    ...>
    <Entry Style="{StaticResource style1}"                  
           ...>
    </Entry>

</controls:CustomBorder>
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.